# AngularJS SPA What's the best way to make a login service with a large app?

Tags: angularjs, html, rest, authentication, single-page-application

I am working on a project with 100+ pages and i am using AngularJS with ui-route and a php REST backend. For authentification i want to use Json Web Token.

I am trying to find the best way to make the login page, but i didn't found a way still, after a lot of googling.

My app allows only logged in users to access it, else they should go to login page.

My main problem is how should i organize the index.html because the login page has totally other template than the rest of the app.

In index.html i have a lot of elements like header and footer which are loaded on all pages, except on login page. So in order to achieve this i used ng-if={{user.isLoggedIn}}, but it's not the right thing to do, i think, because for only one page i must have this condition on all pages.

Another idea is to use two apps, so if the user is not logged in is redirected to the login app (actually redirection, not only change of state, because it uses another master template).

Is there a way in which i keep login page in the SPA, so i have only one app?

Thanks in advance for any valid answer and i hope i've been as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into nested views with UI-Route. You would be able to have $state.login and $state.dashboard any state while logged in could follow with $state.dashboard.home etc. If you want to keep this in one app this may be the easiest solution for you.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Great! Thanks. From what i understood, this can be easily used when you have different templating over the website so the design is inherited from the parent view. Is this correct?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly the design or external/css files are still pulled in by your index file. Not sure if you checked out their plnkr or not but here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview 
since you want to change out the entire page I would throw your first ui-view on the <body> and the subsequent will be where necessary on the dashboard template probably between your header(nav) and footer.

Comment: In index head i would load only the files that run across entire website like, angular.js and the rest i will load when the first level of nesting occurs. If i have index.login and index.website.home lets say, login would load login.css and website will load website.css which is also available in home.